# How to get my Android device to connect in USB Debugging Mode?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, usb-debugging

I have videocon (vt10 - android v4.1 jelly bean) 10 inch tablet.

I want to connect my device to my computer (Windows 7 32-bit) in USB DEBUGGING MODE.

I searched a lot and didn't find any USB drivers for my device, I also contact Company Customer Care but they said that they didnt made any kind of USB drivers for that device.

I also installed PDAnet software for connecting android devices but nothing happens.

Please any one tell me how can I connect this device in debugging mode ?

Answer (score 1):

You need the Android SDK installed on your computer to be able to do anything in the debugging mode. I think that will also install the relevant driver. Try installing it and see if it works.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html